# Use function in a different phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, html

I'm trying to put the client name on a little screen, I saw that when you enter the site it displays the user name, I tried to use the same function, but in mine it is not working.

**Magento code**

```
<div class="welcome-msg">
    <p class="hello"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Hello, %s!', $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomerName())) ?></strong></p>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('From your My Account Dashboard you have the ability to view a snapshot of your recent account activity and update your account information. Select a link below to view or edit information.') ?></p>
</div>
```

**My code**

```
<li class="name-login"><span><?php echo $this->__('Hello, %s!', $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomerName())) ?></span></li>
```

Comment: can you please specify file path where you try to call that function?

Comment: In my code `design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/template/linksblock.phtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not working because there is no function available with name `getCustomerName` in your current class.
You need to use customer helper to get that function as the function is defined in **app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Helper\Data.php** file.

Use below code

```
<li class="name-login"><span><?php echo $this->__('Hello, %s!', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::helper("customer")->getCustomerName())) ?></span></li>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much, it takes the name and surname, you know if you have how to get only the first name? But that's great already

Comment: If you only want customer first name than change `Mage::helper("customer")->getCustomerName()` to `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname()` in your code and it will work.